# Getting chip card PAN or PAN sequence with the sequence of APDU commands: how can I get them?

Tags: nfc, smartcard, apdu

I've got a contactless chip card (not bank or SIM) which I can interact by NFC channel (ISO14443, ISO 7816 Part 4).

All I want to get from this card is getting of UID of the card, which can help me to differ one card from others. As I understand this is PAN value which I can get under the tag '5A'.

Firstly, I can send this command to the card

```
00:a4:04:00:0e:32:50:41:59:2e:53:59:53:2e:44:44:46:30:31:00
```

and get positive answer (SW:9000) with the AID value.

So, I have AID and I can send such command

```
00:a4:04:00:LеnAID:<AID>:00
```

to open file for reading TLV-based info under different Tag, am I right?

But when I send ('5A' - tag for PAN)

```
00:CA:00:5A:00
```

I have bad response -> `6E:00`

So,

1)Should I change Class value (CLA = 00 for right now)? And for what value?

2)Maybe I have to change INS value for READ RECORD (B0 or B2 or something else) because "The kernel uses the value of the AFL (i.e. tag ‘94’) to issue one or more READ RECORD commands retrieve the Application data elements", in my case tag '5A' for PAN.
If so, what the complete workflow should be for getting PAN?

**UPD.**
When I sent

```
ff:ca:00:00:00
```

I receive

```
6e:00
```

Comment: If you mean contactless UID than have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13051167/5128464). PAN/PAN Sequence number is very specific for EMV payment cards. Good luck!

Comment: The term *UID* suggests a precision, which simply does not exists in smart cards in general. It wholly depends on the card in question, which you did not specify. For a start see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9514684/1435475).

Comment: @vlp ff:ca:00:00:00 didn't fit to me, I received 6e:00. Maybe this is that my card is not payment card but more like a token

Comment: @vlp Hmmm, tried to get info from my Mastercard with Paypass. The same answer, 6E:00, it's strange for me

Comment: @AlexZezekalo I have just send `FF CA 00 00 00` command to a Mastercard credit card and I got the UID of the card. What card and reader are you using? If the card is ISO 14443 you can use this command to get the UID. It is defined in PCSC extensions for contactless. Do you get an "ATR" when you tap your card to the your reader? You can check PCSC specs to identify which type of card you are using.

Answer (score 2):

For unknown for me reason I couldn't get positive answer on command

```
FF:CA:00:00:00
```

I got answer `6E:00`

But I found another way how to get card info. I have to execute not one but a sequence of commands:

1) Firstly I have to find out the AID of the applet. If you know AID you can skip this step (2PAY.SYS.DDF in my case)

```
00:a4:04:00:0e:32:50:41:59:2e:53:59:53:2e:44:44:46:30:31:00
```

2) Then SELECT APPLICATION

```
00 A4 04 00 AID-Lenth AID
```

3) After that we GET PROCESSING OPTIONS

```
80 A8 00 00 02 83 00 00
```

4) And READ RECORD

```
00 B2 01 14 00
```

For decoding TLV-response I use this utility - https://www.emvlab.org/tlvutils
In response I got not only 5A tag but also others and for right now I have to parse the whole R-APDU for fetching particular tag value.

Is there any java-libs for parsing TLV-response?

Comment: Have a look at [javaemvreader](https://github.com/sasc999/javaemvreader).