# Using TapLinx SDK for Java, NOT Android, for reading MIFARE DESFire contactless smart cards

Tags: java, sdk, mifare, desfire, taplinx

I have developed successful solutions for reading DESFire smart cards used in Croatian public services, both for:

1. Dot Net. Multi platform, using pcsc-sharp and "raw" APDU approach.
2. Android. Using TapLinx SDK for Android and high level-approach. For example: `myDesFire.getUID()` instead of raw APDU commands.

Right now, I'm trying to develop multi platform solution in Java, using TapLinx SDK for Java and high-level approach.

I rely on `javax.smartcardio` for polling connected card terminal to see when smart card is inserted or removed, and it works perfectly. In my testing app (JavaFX if that matters), in `onCardInserted` event, I'm calling my own `cardLogic` method. That method tries to connect to smart card.

In Android, it is very simple:

```
public static Card cardLogic(final Intent intent, NxpNfcLib nxpNfcLib, MyCardKeys keys) {

//... some code ommited for brevity

desFireEV = DESFireFactory.getInstance().getDESFireEV2(nxpNfcLib.getCustomModules());

desFireEV.getReader().connect();

byte[] uid = desFireEV.getUID();

// ...and so on.
```

In Java, similar method of mine is:

```
public static Card cardLogic(CardTerminal terminal, MyCardKeys keys) {

//... some code ommited for brevity

javax.smartcardio.Card javaCard = terminal.connect("*");

desFire = DESFireFactory.getInstance().getDESFireEV2(TapLinx.getCustomModules());

// **NOW WHAT!???**

desFire.getReader().connect(); // **This does not work, of course. HOW TO connect context of javaCard object with getting a concrete reader, so that...**

byte[] uid = desFire.getUID(); // **... I can do this without raising an exception?**
```

So, questions are those in comments of the above code snippets. I'm totally stucked. Probably missing something obvious. but I can not figure out the solution, not even when reading code of both sample desktop apps.

Please help.

I also tried raw APDU approach without TapLinx SDK, using just `javax.smartcardio`, but since `smartcardio` was actually developed to support contact cards, one can not make more complex operations targeting contactless cards. So, I can read DESFire's UID, select identity app, read app IDs, but I can not read BER TLV files, for example, even if not encrypted.

Comment: I never worked with Java-TapLinx, but "byte[] uid = desFire.getUID(); // **... I can do this without raising an exception?**" should be easy to resolve: the getUid requires an authentication with any key (as you are on Master Application level at this point: authenticate with the MasterKey (0x00) BEFORE you are going to ask for the UID.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
However, I do not need any authentication to get an UID of those cards, be that using raw APDU, `byte[] cmd = [0xFF, 0xCA, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00]` in Dot Net, or `desFire.getUID()` in TapLinx SDK for Android. Neither for accessing file 0 and reading app IDs from there.
So, something else has to be done.

Comment: As the getUID command returns encrypted data it is required to have a sessionKey that is available only after an authentication (with any key). So it is mandatory to authenticate BEFORE you run the getUID command. When communicating using some "raw" commands (like using the IsoDep class in Android) you get an UID that **may** be the real cardUID but - depending on DESFire tag setup - can be a random one (that looks like the real of course). To get the "real" cardUID you use the getUID command as described before. [TapLinx will fire an exception on errors like missing authentication].

Comment: I guess that each card personalizer has its own access policy. On cards I work with, used by Croatian public services, you certainly can get UID without any authentication. But for example, for older Croatian student cards ("iksica") issued before school year 2022/2023, you couldn't get UID before selection of a specific applet.

Anyway, I'm still stucked regarding TapLinx Java SDK. There's no response on [NXP Community](https://community.nxp.com/t5/Other-NXP-Products/Using-TapLinx-SDK-for-Java/m-p/1812221) portal, neither any mention of my problem in defunct TapLinx Developer Forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution. So, in case someone encounters similar problem
code goes like this. BTW, the key is in the **`setTransceive`** method!?!?!!!
And, it seems that I initially put this answer to the [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514684/what-apdu-command-gets-card-id/13178889) by mistake.

```
MyApp.TapLinx.getCustomModules().setTransceive(new MyCardApduHandler(new MyCardReader(terminal)));
desFire = DESFireFactory.getInstance().getDESFireEV2(MyApp.TapLinx.getCustomModules());
desFire.getReader().connect();

// Read UID.
byte[] uid = desFire.getUID();
// To do anything further, and unlike Android , you have to set Command Set to ISO.
desFire.setCommandSet(IDESFireEV1.CommandSet.ISO);
// Select ID app...
desFire.selectApplication(0);
// ...and so on
```

`MyCardApduHandler` is barebone:

```
public class MyCardApduHandler implements IApduHandler {
    IReader reader;

    public SCardApduHandler(IReader reader) {
        this.reader = reader;
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] apduExchange(byte[] bytes) {
        return reader.transceive(bytes);
    }

    @Override
    public IReader getReader() {
        return reader;
    }
}
```

`MyCardReader` is as follows:

```
public class MyCardReader implements IReader {
    CardTerminal mTerminal;
    CardChannel mKanal;
    Card mJavaCard;
    ProtocolDetails mProtokol;
    boolean isConnected = false;

    public SCardReader(CardTerminal terminal) {
        mTerminal = terminal;
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] transceive(byte[] bytes) {
        ResponseAPDU res;
        try {
            res = mKanal.transmit(new CommandAPDU(bytes));
        } catch (CardException e) {
            throw new NxpNfcLibException(e, e.getMessage());
        }
        return res.getBytes();
    }

    @Override
    public void connect() {
        if (!isConnected) {
            try {
                mTerminal.waitForCardPresent(0);
                mJavaCard = mTerminal.connect("*");
                mKanal = mJavaCard.getBasicChannel();
                mProtokol = new ProtocolDetails();
                mProtokol.uid = Commands.uid(mKanal);
                // TODO: Other components of the protocol.
                isConnected = true;
            } catch (CardException e) {
                throw new NxpNfcLibException(e, e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        if (isConnected) {
            try {
                if (mKanal.getChannelNumber() != 0) mKanal.close();
                mJavaCard.disconnect(false);
                isConnected = false;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new NxpNfcLibException(e, e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isConnected() {
        return isConnected;
    }

    @Override
    public void setTimeout(long l) {
        throw new NotSupportedException("SCardReader: metoda setTimeout nije podržana. ");
    }

    @Override
    public long getTimeout() {
        throw new NotSupportedException("SCardReader: metoda getTimeout nije podržana. ");
    }

    @Override
    public ProtocolDetails getProtocolDetails() {
        return mProtokol;
    }
}
```

And, `Commands.uid(mKanal)` is achieved with raw APDU:

```
public static byte[] uid(CardChannel kanal) throws CardException, RuntimeException {
    CommandAPDU cmd = new CommandAPDU(new byte[] { (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xCA, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00 });
    ResponseAPDU res = kanal.transmit(cmd);
    if (res.getSW1() != 0x90 && res.getSW2() != 0x00) throw new RuntimeException(String.format("uid: greška SW1 SW2 = %02X %02X", res.getSW1(), res.getSW2()));
    return res.getData();
}
```

Comment: In the thread I initially and mistakenly posted this answer, @MichaelFehr commented about UID _from the protocol_ and UID _on the smart card_ that is accessible only after authentication. He linked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13178889/23360594), but I still do not understand where's that UID _from the protocol_ actually written. 

By the way, in cards I work with, for 4 different public services, it is obviously UID _from the protocol_ that matters. It always starts with 04, is immutable, and accessible without authentication.

So why are there two UIDs at all?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to the original question but an explanation on the comment.

When the NFC technology started to get popular (around 2010, see https://www.paragon-rfid.com/en/the-history-of-nfc/ and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-field_communication for more details) nearly nobody was concerned abot "Privacy". But nowadays with connected systems and large data centers a lot of people rethink their opinion.

Think of a country where the NFC tag readers are connected to a data center that observes each NFC tag that is tapped to a reader ("Smart City" projects e.g. are combining access control, public transport, vendor machines with one card). What is the consequence of a static and unique NFC card UID ? Yes, you are getting **trackable** by the system as each tag is assigned to one person (the card holder).

For that reason the "newer" NFC tags provide an option to show a **random UID** (the UID may start with 08h) on tapping. You asked about this: it is part of the anti-collision workflow between the NFC reader and NFC device. This protocol usually ends with a "beep" of the reader and in this protocol the UID is exchanged with the reader.

For the same reason any Android device using "Host Based Card Emulation" ("HCE") is not giving a static but always a random UID.

If I (as a card issuer) e.g. config my Mifare DESFire EVx tag to "reveal" a random UID you will observe the same behaviour - each time you tap the tag to the reader the reader will detect a random number that makes it useless for tracking purposes.

If e.g. an access control system relies only the UID transmitted by protocol this system gets useless as well, as there is no "whitelist" to check the (random) UID against).

How to retrieve the real card's UID: A Mifare DESFire will give it's ("real" and unique) card UID after a the command (51h) and after an Authentication Session has run. During this Authentication a "sessionkey" is defined between both partners (reader and tag) and the tag will send the card UID in an encrypted form. Any NFC card reader observer will only notice a byte sequence that is random and not trackable. Only the system behind the reader who has the knowledge about the authentication key is been able to decrypt the data and can match the card UID against a whitelist or is doing something else).

To anser your last question *"So why are there two UIDs at all?"*: the UID by protocol is just for anti-collision purpose and the "real" card UID is for whitelist purposes.

Comment: Thanks for info. It is actually more insightful than just for pure "thanks" because it brings all those privacy issues to the spotlight. Sooner or later, someone will be concerned about those issues here in Croatia, regarding both smart cards I work with, and others. So, service providers will actually be forced to **read** those cards, not just their UID.

I've never actually dive deep in smart cards protocols, always (until now) just got a few test cards, sometimes with old piece of reading-code, and was asked to bring a utility library to life.